# MongoDB : return empty field when printing document id

Tags: mongodb

For some reason, I need to clean my datas in MongoDB by trimming specific values.

To do so, I process as follow:

```
db.collection.find({"param1":{$regex: /^\s.*/}}).forEach(
    function(doc){
    tmp = doc["param1"].trim()
    db.collection.update({"_id": doc._id}, {"$set":{ "param1":tmp}});
    })
```

From there, I get an error. Now I do :

```
db.collection.find({"param1":{$regex: /^\s.*/}}).forEach(
    function(doc){
    var tid = doc._id;
    print(tid);
    })
```

It returns empty fields:

```
>/* 1 */
>{}
>/* 2 */
>{}
>/* 3 */
>{}
>/* 4 */
>{}
```

So I guess the previous error come from the update not finding the id. Any ideas about why I get those empty values ?

Comment: Hard to say, without seeing the full data. Can you run `db.collection.find()` in the mongo shell, for example, and show us what the data looks like? It isn't possible to have a document without a unique _id field, in any case.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't since those are private datas from my company.
However, I noticed that when I do the update command, it updates a few documents before getting an error. What I did for the moment was to run the command several times until there are no document left.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error was due to Robomongo.

Executing the script directly in a shell is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that lands here, using the above as an example you need to add a *toString* call to the end of the Id.

```
db.collection.find({"param1":{$regex: /^\s.*/}}).forEach(
    function(doc){
    var tid = doc._id;
    print(tid.tostring());
})
```